# Camera in MacBook after a few seconds of video conference using openvidu will be freeze

Tags: webrtc, openvidu, safari-11

I create a video conferencing web application and I have a problem with the last update of mac OS (Big Sur v11)

When I connected to the conference everything was okay but after a while, maybe 10 seconds camera stopped and in the browser URL field, the camera icon next to the URL changed to the microphone. in this step, the video will be frozen and after maybe a 10-second the microphone will be stopped.

I have no problem with Chrome or Firefox, but I have it just in the safari.

Comment: Show some [mre] that is some source code in your question

Comment: This problem was related to the video codec at that time. In order to solve this problem at that moment by changing the video codec, our problem was solved but a few months ago I had a meeting with the team and in the new updates, safari has been solved this problem.